# Changes to CSS in inspector stylesheet apply but those same changes will not apply in my CSS file

Tags: html, css

Bit of a strange occurrence with my web page, currently trying to resize the font of a facebook like button I have on my website.

Currently the HTML I'm targeting is:

```
<span id="u_0_3">2.1k people like this. Be the first of your friends.</span>
```

In the google chrome console adding either of the following will change the font

1.

`#u_0_3 { font-size: 14px }`

2.

`span#u_0_3 { font-size: 14px }`

but adding either of these lines of code to my web pages stylesheet has absolutely no effect. No clue how to proceed from here as it works in one stylesheet and not the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the styles aren't updating when adding the code to your stylesheet as opposed to in the browser is because you're trying to a stylesheet on an iframe, which isn't possible. You can however add the styles using jQuery or something along those lines.

Try this...

```
$("iframe#idhere").contents().find("span#u_0_3").css('font-size', '14px');
```

Comment: Thumbs up for intuition

Comment: Woops, I probably should've included more code so viewers knew it was inside an iframe. That being said you're absolutely right jQuery line works perfectly. Thanks Nikki!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have added CSS file reference in your HTML.

Also, clear browser cache and load the page.

Comment: Stylesheet is linked in HTML (and has been for a few months now) browser cache cleared and page reloaded. I can edit my main.css file in my chrome console and still not have it take any effect despite every other CSS declaration working perfectly fine.